Needing to reload data on route change using same component - React TSX
Right now, I'm having trouble as my data that I am receiving from Firebase Firestore is able to load on both routes, however, it only does so if I click twice on the route link otherwise the old data persists between route changes. My goal is to have the data reset on route changes.
Here is my code for a grid of part numbers that I am receiving from Firestore to display:
var arrSnap:QueryDocumentSnapshot[] = [];

async function populateGrid(){
const currentRoute = useLocation()
var program = currentRoute.replace('/parts-list/', '');


var querySnapshot;
if (program === 'First'){
     querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "Programs", "----", program, "-----", "Parts"));

}else if(program === 'Second'){
     querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "Programs", "----", program, "-----", "Parts"));

}else{

}

const _arrSnap:QueryDocumentSnapshot[] = [];

querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    _arrSnap.push(doc);
  });
  console.log(_arrSnap[0].get("PN"));
  arrSnap = [..._arrSnap];
  
 }




export default function CardGrid(){
   populateGrid();




return (
    <>
    <div className="tlCont">
        <div className="gridCont">
           {[...arrSnap].map((e, i) => {
return (

<div className="gridItm" key={arrSnap[i].get("PN")}>
    <Card > 
Part Number: {arrSnap[i].get("PN")}
<br></br>
Description: {arrSnap[i].get("DESCRIPTION")}
<br></br>
Form Tool: {arrSnap[i].get("FORM TOOL")}
<br></br>
Trim Tool: {arrSnap[i].get("TRIM TOOL")}
</Card>

    </div>
)


           })}
        </div>

    </div>
    </>
    )
}

I suspect it has to do with calling the function "populateGrid()" inside the component that is loaded.

Issue

populateGrid is called as an unintentional side-effect
populateGrid mutates a global arrSnap array reference. This doesn't trigger a CardGrid component rerender so the component needs to be triggered some other way to rerender, i.e. like clicking the route link a second time. The subsequent render exposes the mutated arrSnap array value.

Solution

populateGrid should be called as ann intentional side-effect, e.g. use the useEffect hook
Store the fetched Firebase doc data into local React state so that when it's updated it triggers a component rerender.

Example:
export default function CardGrid() {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();

  const [arrSnap, setArrSnap] = React.useState<QueryDocumentSnapshot[]>([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const populateGrid = async () => {
      const program = /* use pathname to compute program */;
    
      let doc;

      switch(program) {
        case "First":
          doc = collection(db, "Programs", "----", program, "-----", "Parts");
          break;

        case "Second":
          doc = collection(db, "Programs", "----", program, "-----", "Parts");
          break;

        default:
      }

      try {
        const querySnapshot = await getDocs(doc);
        const arrSnap: QueryDocumentSnapshot[] = [];
    
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          arrSnap.push(doc);
        });

        setArrSnap(arrSnap);
      } catch(error) {
        // handle/ignore
      }
    };

    populateGrid();
  }, [pathname]);
   
  return (
    <div className="tlCont">
      <div className="gridCont">
        {arrSnap.map((item) => (
          <div className="gridItm" key={item.get("PN")}>
            <Card> 
              Part Number: {item.get("PN")}
              <br></br>
              Description: {item.get("DESCRIPTION")}
              <br></br>
              Form Tool: {item.get("FORM TOOL")}
              <br></br>
              Trim Tool: {item.get("TRIM TOOL")}
            </Card>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

It may be worth it to abstract the logic into a custom hook.
Basic example:
const usePopulateGrid = <T extends unknown>() => {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();

  const [data, setData] = React.useState<T[]>([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const populateGrid = async () => {
      const program = /* use pathname to compute program */;
    
      let doc;

      switch(program) {
        case "First":
          doc = collection(db, "Programs", "----", program, "-----", "Parts");
          break;

        case "Second":
          doc = collection(db, "Programs", "----", program, "-----", "Parts");
          break;

        default:
      }

      try {
        const querySnapshot = await getDocs(doc);
        const data: T[] = [];
    
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          data.push({
            id: doc.id,
            partNumber: doc.get("PN"),
            description: doc.get("DESCRIPTION"),
            formTool: doc.get("FORM TOOL"),
            trimTool: doc.get("TRIM TOOL")
          } as T);
        });

        setData(data);
      } catch(error) {
        // handle/ignore
      }
    };

    populateGrid();
  }, [pathname]);

  return data;
};

interface GridData {
  id: string;
  partNumber: string;
  description: string;
  formTool: string;
  trimTool: string;
}

export default function CardGrid() {
  const gridData = usePopulateGrid<GridData>();
   
  return (
    <div className="tlCont">
      <div className="gridCont">
        {gridData.map((item) => (
          <div className="gridItm" key={item.id}>
            <Card> 
              Part Number: {item.partNumber}
              <br></br>
              Description: {item.description}
              <br></br>
              Form Tool: {item.formTool}
              <br></br>
              Trim Tool: {item.trimTool}
            </Card>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}


The idea of using a custom hook has helped a lot. All I had to do to ensure the interface properties aligned with the data from the database was to add the getters in the querySnapshot foreach loop.
